# Is there a way to hide the bubbles when you hover over an element i devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

In Chrome and Chromium, when you hover over an element i devtools a bubble appears next to the element on the web page? Is there a way to disable it?

My problem is that it is in the way for me to see if 2 elements align.
[image: No hover, all elements are clearly visible]

[image: Hover over span to see if aligns with the line above but the bubble covers it]

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently holding down `Ctrl` while hovering will hide the bubble. Note that you must hold down `Ctrl` before hovering.